# Delete group/id and the correspondng rows, from a datrame based on certain condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the below dataframe:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd

#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
               4, 4, 4,
               5, 5, 5, 5, 5,5, 5, 5,5],
        'cycle': [1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
                  1,2, 
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,
                  1,2, 3,
                  1,2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,],
        'Salary': [7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   4, 4,
                   8,9,10,11,12,13,
                   8,9,10,
                   7, 7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,],
        'Children': ['No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes',
                      'No',  'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',],
        'Days': [123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 96, 120,
                 15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141,
                 141,123, 128,
                 123, 128, 66, 123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 52,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("df = \n", df)
```

The above dataframe looks as such:

[image]

Here, every id has different cycles as per the 'cycle' column. For example,

id-1 has maximum 11 cycles.

id-2 has maximum 2 cycles.

id-3 has maximum 6 cycles.

id-4 has maximum 3 cycles.

id-5 has maximum 9 cycles.

I have a certain threshold limit on 'cycles'. Let's say cycle_threshold = 3

If maximum cycles for and id <= cycle_threshold, then delete the entire group/id

For example,

For id-2 and id-4, since maximum cycles are 2 and 3 respectively, the id's and the correspondng rows get deleted from the dataframe

However, the rest of the group's/id's remain as it is.

The result looks as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how do I achieve this task in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for aggregate values to Series with same index like original DataFrame, so possible compare by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) for filter greater values what is same like remove equal or less values by threshold:

```
cycle_threshold = 3

df1 = df[df.groupby('id')['cycle'].transform('max').gt(cycle_threshold)]
```

Another idea:

```
cycle_threshold = 3

m = df.groupby('id')['cycle'].max().gt(cycle_threshold)
df1 = df[df['id'].isin(m.index[m])]
```

---

```
print (df1)
    id  cycle  Salary Children  Days
0    1      1       7       No   123
1    1      2       7      Yes   128
2    1      3       7      Yes    66
3    1      4       8      Yes    66
4    1      5       9      Yes   120
5    1      6      10       No   141
6    1      7      11       No    52
7    1      8      12      Yes    96
8    1      9      13      Yes   120
9    1     10      14      Yes   141
10   1     11      15       No    52
13   3      1       8       No    15
14   3      2       9      Yes   123
15   3      3      10      Yes   128
16   3      4      11       No    66
17   3      5      12       No   120
18   3      6      13      Yes   141
22   5      1       7       No   123
23   5      2       7      Yes   128
24   5      3       9       No    66
25   5      4      10       No   123
26   5      5      11      Yes   128
27   5      6      12      Yes    66
28   5      7      13      Yes   120
29   5      8      14      Yes   141
30   5      9      15       No    52
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do groupby and filter

```py
out = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda g: g['cycle'].max() > 3)
```

```
print(out)

    id  cycle  Salary Children  Days
0    1      1       7       No   123
1    1      2       7      Yes   128
2    1      3       7      Yes    66
3    1      4       8      Yes    66
4    1      5       9      Yes   120
5    1      6      10       No   141
6    1      7      11       No    52
7    1      8      12      Yes    96
8    1      9      13      Yes   120
9    1     10      14      Yes   141
10   1     11      15       No    52
13   3      1       8       No    15
14   3      2       9      Yes   123
15   3      3      10      Yes   128
16   3      4      11       No    66
17   3      5      12       No   120
18   3      6      13      Yes   141
22   5      1       7       No   123
23   5      2       7      Yes   128
24   5      3       9       No    66
25   5      4      10       No   123
26   5      5      11      Yes   128
27   5      6      12      Yes    66
28   5      7      13      Yes   120
29   5      8      14      Yes   141
30   5      9      15       No    52
```